# Solving the functional equation $f(a + b) = a + f(b)$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

How would you solve:
$$f(a+b)=a+f(b) ?$$
It seems similar to the Cauchy equation $$f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b),$$ but I'm not sure what to do with this. I have a feeling the only solution is $f(k)=k$ but idk.
Thanks for the help, Guys!

Comment: what if you have $f(a) = a$  ?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint** Setting $b = 0$ gives $$f(a) = a + f(0),$$ so any such function is determined by $f(0)$.

Answer (score 3):

If $f(a + b) = a + f(b)$ for every $a$ and $b$, then, putting $c = f(0)$,  $f(x) = f(x + 0) = x + f(0) = x + c$ for any $x$. Conversely for any given $c$ if you define $f(x) = x + c$, then $f$ satisfies $f(a+b) = a + b + c = a + f(b)$. So the solutions are all functions of the form $f(x) = x + c$.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to notice that in
$$f(a+b)=a+f(b)$$
the left hand side is symmetric in $a$ and $b$, while the right hand side is not, and we can exploit this: swap $a$ and $b$. The left hand side remains unchanged, and hence so must the right hand side, and so we must have that
$$a+f(b)=b+f(a)$$
for all $a$ and $b$.
This gives us that for all $a$ and $b$,
$$f(a)-a=f(b)-b$$ and so
$$f(x)-x$$
is constant. We thus have that $f(x)=x+c$ for all $x$ for some constant $c$, and we can easily check that any such function satisfies the functional equation.

Comment: Nice and intuitive